# convert string number with bytes to integer in rails ("32MB" -> 32.megabytes)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, type-conversion

I would like to convert a string that includes KB, MB, GB as part of the string to the integer equivalent.

Examples

```
"24kb" = 24.kilobytes = 24576
"32MB" = 32.megabytes = 33554432
"64 GB" = 64.gigabytes = 68719476736
```

I can go the other way, integer to string, using...

```
>> ActiveSupport::NumberHelper.number_to_human_size(68719476736)
=> "64 GB"
```

I tried...

```
>> Integer("64GB")
=> ArgumentError: invalid value for Integer(): "64GB"
```

I can create my own method doing something like...

```
  def convert_size_to_integer(size)
    size.downcase!
    if(size.end_with? 'kb')
      size.to_i.kilobytes
    elsif(size.end_with? 'mb')
      size.to_i.megabytes
    elsif(size.end_with? 'gb')
      size.to_i.gigabytes
    else
      size.to_i
    end
  end
```

but this is dissatisfying and seems like there is probably something already out there to do this.  And, of course, I could simplify this and make it more robust using regex.  But I am trying to avoid writing this at all by finding something that already exists.

Any suggestions?

Comment: _“I am trying to avoid writing this at all by finding something that already exists”_ – StackOverflow is mainly about writing your own code. Asking for software recommendations is off-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's [filesize](https://rubygems.org/gems/filesize/versions/0.1.1)

It's quite trivial to write your own:
But you can write your own:

```rb
def convert_size_to_bytes
  md = match(/^(?<num>\d+)\s?(?<unit>\w+)?$/)
  md[:num].to_i * 
      case md[:unit]
      when 'KB'
        1024
      when 'MB'
        1024**2
      when 'GB'
        1024**3
      when 'TB'
        1024**4
      when 'PB'
        1024**5
      when 'EB'
        1024**6
      when 'ZB'
        1024**7
      when 'YB'
        1024**8
      else
        1
      end
    end
```

Comment: This is great.  I made one slight adjustment to upcase the unit so "5kb" and "5KB" both match the kilobyte case.

Comment: filesize looks good too, but it was overkill for my use case.

Comment: @ELRayle I would argue that `1kB` and `1KB` and `1kb` are different things because `k` usually means `1000` whereas `K` is used for `1024` and `B` is a `byte` whereas `b` is a `bit`